# Unity Custom Inspector Platform dependent property section

Tags: unity, cross-platform, ui-design

I want to make a custom inspector for one of my scripts that builds UI elements at runtime. This requires small changes to the default values depending on what platform I'm targeting. How do I add something that is similar to the graphics settings where **there is a default option but each platform is able to override the 
default** setting for a platform specific value?

[image]

I'm looking for the same kind of thing that Unity has for the player settings (Edit -> Project Settings -> Player). This allows you to set the details for each one but you can override them for each platform if they need to be different.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html You can create a custom editor in your script. I don't know if there is a way to change the internal unity UI, the one shown in the image unless you have access to the source code. There is also a direct access from code to some of the properties of Player Settings: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerSettings.html